# Provider and subscriber in SQL Server 2008, can subscriber handle insert/delete?

Tags: sql-server-2008, transactions, replication

Assuming I did all that is needed (consider complete replication) to make server "A" the provider and server "B" the subscriber, if I want to add, delete, update, or insert data, will I be able to do that by connecting to the subscriber?

If yes, will the data change be automatically reflected in the provider?

I am using: C#, ASP.NET, Visual Studio 2008, SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the replication wizard of SSMS, it depends on your configuration:

> **Snapshot publication:**
>   The Publisher sends a snapshot of the published data to Subscribers at scheduled intervals.
>
> **Transactional publication:**
>   The Publisher streams transactions to the Subscribers after they receive an initial snapshot of the published data.
>
> **Transactional publication with updatable subscriptions:**
>   The Publisher streams transactions to SQL Server Subscribers after they receive an initial snapshot of the published data. Transactions originating at the Subscriber are applied at the Publisher.
>
> **Merge publication:**
>   The Publisher and Subscribers can update the published data independently after the Subscribers receive an initial snapshot of the published data. Changes are merged periodically. Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition can only subscribe to merge publications.

It looks like the last two options support what you need. I haven't been able to get replication running at all just now, so I haven't been able to test it.